# Xamp [Apache] não inicia

Tags: apache, xampp

Estou tentando iniciar o apache pelo xampp, porém, não estou tendo sucesso. O erro do Apache_Start.bat é o seguinte:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 176 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: N\xe3o foi poss\xedvel encontrar o m\xf3dulo
```

especificado.

Já instalei, reinstalei o xampp;
Já pesquisei diversos tópicos e assisti vídeos.

Espero que alguém possa me ajudar.

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium (32 Bits)

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui essa duvida já foi resolvida em outra pergunta
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017498/cannot-load-modules-mod-ssl-so-into-server

Comment: Pior que não é isso, tentei fazer de tudo mas não fiz o mais óbvio, que era atualizar o Windows. O cara que formatou ele bloqueou o windows update e nunca tinha atualizado. Aí 538 atualizações depois, funcionou.